# Shortest Seek Time First (SSTF) in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement Shortest Seek Time First (SSTF) algorithm in Linux Command Line.  The commandline is to read the track values from the following line:

```
./disksed 53 98 183 37 122 14 124 65 67
```

and print the following report:

```
SSTF: Start:53 65:12 67:2 37:30 14:23 98:84 122:24 124:2 183:59 Total:236
```

Am I on the right track at all?  I'm not getting the correct values, and I don't exactly know how to proceed.  Below is my code so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 const int ARRAY_SIZE = 9;
 int sstd[ARRAY_SIZE];
 int total2 = 0;
 int temp;

 printf("\nSSTF: Start:");
 printf("%s", argv[1]);
 printf(" ");

 for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
 {
  if (strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 10) - strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10) < 0)
   total2 += (abs(strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 10) - strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10)));
  else
   total2 += (strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 10) - strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10));

  temp = strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 10);
  argv[i + 1] = argv[i + 2];
  argv[i + 2] = (char)temp;
  sstd[i] = strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 10);

  printf("%d", sstd[i]);
  printf(":");
  //Print difference?
  printf(" ");
 }

 printf("Total:");
 printf("%d", total2);
 printf("\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step though the code and see what happens in it?

Comment: Missing a test for ssd.

Comment: Starting by converting all the arguments to numbers and store those numbers in an array. The array size should be based on the number of arguments that were entered on the command line, e.g. `int input[argc-1];`